# Send/redirect/route java.util.logging.Logger (JUL) to Logback using SLF4J?

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

Is it possible to have a typical call to `java.util.logging.Logger` and have it route to Logback using SLF4J? This would be nice since I wouldn't have to refactor the old jul code line by line.

EG, say we have this line:

```
private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MahClass.class.getName());
//...
logger.info("blah blah blah");
```

It would be nice to configure this to call through SLF4J.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. And it is very easy, you don't have to change any source code. You only must change some .jar libraries. Look at this articles - [logging-with-slf4j](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/02/logging-with-slf4j/) - [legacy logging](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html) - [SLF4J logging](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/tag/logback/)

Comment: There is one major benefit by biting the bullet and refactor to slf4j.  Namely that you can use {} in your strings to delay toString() calls.

Comment: Is toString() really a concern with modern JVMs? I realize it is more efficient to avoid toString() calls, but my understanding is that object creation is cheap and that this would fall under premature optimization.

Comment: yes it is really is a concern if you are making rich logging statements. profiling a production system in 2015 on a modern jvm unnecessary calls to create strings for debug statements that are not actual enabled in production is a cpu hotspot for the production system.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's very easy and not a performance issue anymore.

There are two ways documented in the [SLF4J manual](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j). There are also precise examples in the [Javadocs](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.html)

Add jul-to-slf4j.jar to your classpath. Or through maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you don't have logging.properties (for java.util.logging), add this to your bootstrap code:

```
SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

If you have logging.properties (and want to keep it), add this to it:

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

In order to avoid performance penalty, add this contextListener to logback.xml (as of logback version 0.9.25):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <!-- reset all previous level configurations of all j.u.l. loggers -->
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener> 

    ...

</configuration>
```

Comment: Just a note - I had to reload Logback configuration to make this working for me.

Comment: Adding the contextListener configuration was necessary anyway to propagate the logback configuration to the jul logger. So regardless of the performance improvement it was necessary for us.

Comment: It may be related to that bug in some way : http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-404 i.e. without the propagator Logger are not kept and then their level reset.

Comment: `add this to your bootstrap code` spring's bootstrap-code is not used in war-archive for deployment.