# Redirecting logs for JUL to logback using SLF4J LevelChangePropagator fails

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I'm redirecting all logs meant for JUL to logback using `jul-to-slf4j`. But it works if I use the  `SLF4JBridgeHandler` approach but I cannot see the logs getting written when I use more performant `LevelChangePropagator` approach by adding following lines to config files(`logback.xml` & `logback-test.xml`):

```
<configuration debug="true">
      <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"/>
      .......
</configuration>
```

No logs are getting written.

### Edit:

Here is what my full config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">
  <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -> %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>c:/dev/logs_test/log_01.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} -> %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="px10" level="TRACE"/>

    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>   
</configuration>
```

---

Tried with JSF(Myfaces 2.1.8) App on Glassfish 3.1.1

Comment: Why is the root logger configured twice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send/redirect/route java.util.logging.Logger (JUL) to Logback using SLF4J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020545/send-redirect-route-java-util-logging-logger-jul-to-logback-using-slf4j)

Answer (score 4):

Have your tried setting the level of JSF (MyFaces) loggers in your logback.xml config?

```
<configuration debug="false">
  <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator"/>

  <logger name="org.apache.myfaces" level="DEBUG"/>    
</configuration>
```

LevelChangePropagator does not do anything unless there level changes to propagate. The fact that logging in other parts of your application work as you expect, only means that those parts are configured correctly for logback, but not necessarily j.u.l. For MyFaces you want to configure j.u.l. by propagating your logback configuration via LevelChangePropagator.

Comment: I didn't do that for myfaces explicitly however I believe Myfaces would pick that by itself as the rest of libraries & my application code is doing currently. I can see the logs from other parts of my app.

Comment: Now getting Myfaces logs in my netbeans console but not in the log files yet. Also getting messages like `FINE: PWC4451: File cannot be read C:\dev\Px10App\target\Px10App\WEB-INF\classes\org\apache\myfaces\shared\renderkit\ContentTypeUtils.class` in very bulk numbers in console window for several libraries used in the app. Does that alarm something bad!? This started to appear after adding LevelChangePropagator to config.

Comment: You should use forward slashes to define the file name. I've edited your question to this effect.

Comment: Replacing with forward slashes lead to even the other parts of app that wrote logs previously to  file to stop writing.

Comment: Backward slashes are interpreted as escape sequences by Java. You must either use double backslashes '\\' or forward slashes '/'. Using a single backslash is always incorrect.

Comment: I just retried but can't explain why I'm getting logs written through using \ but not using `/`(forward slash)

Comment: Do you have other configuration file lying around? An old log4j.properties maybe?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15740/discussion-between-ceki-and-user01)