# Use MDC in lombok slf4j

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, lombok

I am working on an application which is heavily using lombok Slf4j. I want to attach some identifier to the logs. MDC is the one which solves this problem for Slf4j but I want to use that with lombok slf4j. I searched on the net but couldn't find any resources.
Is there any way or resources that would be helpful?

Comment: What problem do you have? It should work just fine. Show as your code.

Comment: I couldn't find the option of importing MDC (if I added lombok slf4j). If I could add that then only I can set some identifier there.

Answer (score 1):

It is take some configuration but what you need to do.

Put some dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

configure logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%X{x} %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>


    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Add some magic to any class

```
static {
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
}
```

and put it all to work

```
@Log
public class App {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MDC.put("x", "MDC var");
        log.info("log message");
    }
}
```

Run and enjoy your logs:

```
MDC var log message
```

special thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591459/how-to-make-java-util-logging-send-logs-to-logback/51079721#51079721)