# Logging SQL Server (mssql-jdbc) 2017 JDBC via Logback?

Tags: java, sql-server, maven, logging, jdbc

I am trying to view sql statements that go through my application's SQL Server JDBC connector.  We are using mssql-jdbc.  The app uses slf4j as the logging facade and the current implementation is Logback.

According to [their documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/frequently-asked-questions-faq-for-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017) the JDBC driver uses Java Util logging.  As such I have added the bridge for SLF4J to my pom.xml file as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

I have also added an appender using [the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/tracing-driver-operation?view=sql-server-2017) that looks like this:

```
    <logger name="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Statement" level="FINER" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </logger>
```

However, no logging statements are ever seen.  I have tried many different ways to configure the appender.  Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: These SO questions answer the generic question of redirecting a java.util logging app to logback, but it is not working for this JDBC driver:

- [Send/redirect/route java.util.logging.Logger (JUL) to Logback using SLF4J?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020545/send-redirect-route-java-util-logging-logger-jul-to-logback-using-slf4j)
- [How to make java.util.logging send logs to Logback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41591459/how-to-make-java-util-logging-send-logs-to-logback)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I am answering in case someone has the same issue.

You added `jul-to-slf4j` which is good, but you also need to configure SLF4jHandlers:

1. Add `logging.properties` with the following:

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
```

2. Load this file when your application starts. For this step, you have two choices:

- Start your application with the `java.util.logging.config.file` pointing to the location of your `logging.properties` file. For example: `java -jar -java.util.logging.config.file=/path/to/logging.properties`
- Or, load the configuration file when your application is starting:

```
try (InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/logging.properties")) {
    LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // Handle error
}
```

And it should be good! :)