# Logback does not log JUL fine level

Tags: java, logback, java.util.logging

I am fixing a legacy JSF application running on tomcat 7.

UserAccessBB.java

```
package beans;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class UserAccessBB {
private static final Logger LOG = 
Logger.getLogger(UserAccessBB.class.getName());

public UserAccessBB() {
    LOG.fine("UserAccessBB");
```

logback.xml

```
<logger name="beans" level="TRACE" additivity="false">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</logger>
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

maven

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.20</version>
    </dependency>
```

The file is copied to WEB-INF/classes

The log file contains only INFO and higher level logs from this class. Lower levels are printed only when I modify the root logger. Where is the issue?

Comment: Bugs and limitations in Logback. Reading the comments from Brice at https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407321/3080094 - you probably need Logback 1.0.3 at a minimum to get it working without source code changes.

Comment: Thank you, it looks promising.

Comment: Upgrade to the current version did not help. I had to add  a contextListener as recommended in the linked answer.

Comment: The contextListener uses a LevelChangePropagator which is only available after 0.9.25 (and bug-fixed in 1.0.3), and you were using 0.9.20. I guess the upgrade and the contextListener combined did the trick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For future reference and googlers:

To Logback be able to propagate its configuration to JCL (java.util.logging) it is neccessary to add

```
<contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
    <!-- reset all previous level configurations of all j.u.l. loggers -->
    <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
</contextListener>
```

and use the current version. Cudos to @vanOekel. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20407321/1639556 for details.

Comment: Possible typo in JCL -> change to JUL. I am assuming the edit queue is full for that reason ;)